# Best way for Roles Authorization in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have looked into many Api's for roles authorization like

```
http://jedireza.github.io/drywall/
 https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth
 http://nodetoolbox.com/categories/Authentication
 https://github.com/dresende/node-roles
 https://github.com/CatChen/redis-user
 https://npmjs.org/package/connect-roles
```

all of them provide good functionality for roles authorization (defining roles,and forming groups) assigning different permissions for different roles.
But i want is such a functionality in which an html tag can be configured for a role that whether a role has the permission to a button or an option of select.
I mean we can already find automated functionality for assigning a whole page to a user but not a html tag by these api's.
I hope i am explaining enough.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I wrote another one at http://github.com/deitch/cansecurity but I am having a hard time understanding what functionality you want. Can you throw up a jsfiddle or gist showing what code that actually used it would look like, and then we can worry about backend implementation?